# Passing values from Action to model in Struts 2

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2

I try to figure out how to pass values created in Action class to model(jsp view in my case). I'm new to Struts 2 framework.

My case:

1. I get a parameter from request url.
2. I use this value to generate objects of my own class - Product (I do it in execute method).
3. And then I want to inject the list of Product class objects to jsp view.

My question is - how can I insert objects of my own class in jsp view.

My implementation of Action class:

```
public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport {

private int n;

public int getN() {
    return n;
}

public void setN(int n) {
    this.n = n;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {
    List<Product> products = Service.getProducts(n);//I want to inject this to jsp view
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/docs/tutorials.html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much like how you specified a *setter* to inject incoming parameters into your `ProductAction`, you'll need to expose parameters that you wish to make available inside whatever your view technology choice happens to be, whether that is jsp, ftl, vm, etc.  To do that, you need to provide a *getter*.

```
public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport {
  private Integer n;
  private Collection<Product> products;

  @Override
  public String execute() throws Exception {
    // you may want to add logic for when no products or null is returned.
    this.products = productService.getProducts( n );
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  // this method allows 'n' to be visible to the view technology if needed.
  public Integer getN() {
    return n; 
  }

  // this method allows the request to set 'n'
  public void setN(Integer n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  // makes the collection of products visible in the view technology.
  public Collection<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
  }      
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. After providing a getter, desired objects are visible in a view :)